# Is this scratch work overly complicated for a proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

**Prove if $F \subseteq P(B)$ then $\bigcup F \subseteq B$**

$F \subseteq P(A)$ rewritten as $\forall(A\in F \to A\in P(B))$

$\bigcup F \subseteq B$ rewritten as $\forall y[ (y\in \{x \mid \exists A(A\in F  \wedge x\in A)\} )\to (y \in B) ]$

Now I have to prove $y \in B$.

Since $y \in A, A \in F, A\in P(B)$ and  $y\in P(B)$, we can conclude that $y\in B$ because of $y$ belonging to the power set.

Now assuming my logic is correct (fingers crossed!), is this too overly complicated (not as a proof, but a process of arriving at the proof)?

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Are you required to make this proof formal and include a lot of symbolic notation? Because a proof in natural language would be far better.

Comment: no its not required at all (it is not homework, just some self-study)

Comment: @Zeeshan, \cup  is the symbol for union. Please go through this [tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You're expected to type your question using proper formatting.

Comment: @Sahiba i think its fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is hard to follow and according to my view indeed overly complicated.

This alternative proof might convince you that things can be done more easily.

---

Let $x\in\bigcup F$.

Then (by definition) $x\in y\in F$ for some $y$.

Then on base of $F=\wp(B)$ we conclude that $y\in\wp(B)$ or equivalently $y\subseteq B$.

Then from $x\in y\wedge y\subseteq B$ it follows that $x\in B$.

Proved is now that $x\in\bigcup F\implies x\in B$ or equivalently $\bigcup F\subseteq B$, as requested.